# NLog remove files which are 3 months old

Tags: logging, nlog

I want to log data into small files (<10Mb) and I want to configure Nlog to remove files which are older then 3 months. My configuration is

```
  <target xsi:type="File"
      archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveAboveSize="10000000"
```

I don't use maxArchiveFiles option because I don't want to strict files count. It can be 1 or 100 or 10000. I just need to remove files according to their age. Is it possible to do with Nlog?

Comment: You are waiting for someone to resolve this issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog 4.7 has been released and introduces the new option `maxArchiveFiles` for NLog FileTarget:

```
  <target xsi:type="File"
      archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveAboveSize="10000000"
      maxArchiveDays="93" />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files